# Upgrade to Artifactory OSS 5.4, and Artifactoy won't start

Tags: artifactory

I have upgraded from Artifactoy 5.1 to 5.4.  Now Artifactory will now start.  Getting the following error:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
2017-06-22 09:59:34,971 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:243) - Got response from Access server after 2687 ms, continuing.
2017-06-22 09:59:35,387 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Bad credentials","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:222) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:184) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:93) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:114) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate service admin token using bootstrap credentials.
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.createAndStoreServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:110) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.bootstrapServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:79) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:42) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:227) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:216) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:211) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:228) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.0.jar:na]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 401:{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Bad credentials","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}]}
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:312) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:299) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createToken(AccessHttpClient.java:133) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.token.TokenClientImpl.create(TokenClientImpl.java:36) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.createAndStoreServiceAdminToken(AccessClientBootstrap.java:103) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
2017-06-22 09:59:41,768 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:188) - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null
Jun 22, 2017 10:04:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
```

Comment: Can you share more details about how you performed the upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs due to a missing step during the [upgrade process](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingtotheLatestVersion). As mentioned in the wiki page, as part of the upgrade, you need to remove the existing $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin folder and copy over the new one from the extracted zip file.

This step is crucial, as it contains a property which makes the Access service to be bundled with Artifactory. When this property is missing, the Access service creates a new database with a new admin token, which is different than the existing one. This results in the 401 error that you're seeing, which prevents Artifactory from being restarted.

In order to overcome this issue, follow the steps of the upgrade process, including the removal of the existing bin folder.

Comment: [RTFACT-14477](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14477) contains the relevant properties: `artifactory.access.client.serverUrl.override` and `artifactory.access.server.bundled`.